# Php 7 "cannot use string offset as an array"

Tags: php

We've recently upgraded to Php 7.4 and are encountering a potential fatal error alert for the following code block:

```
$total              = 0;
$balance            = 0;
if (is_array($company['history']) && ($histCount = count($company['history']))) {
    for ($i = $histCount - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $total   += $company['history'][$i]['amt_total'];
        $balance += $company['history'][$i]['due'];
        $company['history'][ $i ]['balance'] = $balance; // EA flags as potential fatal error
        $company['history'][ $i ]['total']   = $total;   // EA flags as potential fatal error
    }
}
```

Each `history` element in the `$company` has (among others) `amt_total`, `due`, `balance`, and `total` initialized, with the last two being initialized to `0`.

EA flags the two lines indicated, saying "Could provoke a PHP Fatal error (cannot use string offset as an array)."

Grateful to anyone who can help me understand what's wrong here.

ADDITIONAL INFO
Someone asked where the code for defining `$company` comes from...

```
foreach ($this->orderList as $order) {
    if ($order['amt_paid'] !== $order['real_amt_paid'] && !empty($order['real_amt_paid'])) {
        $order['amt_paid'] = $order['real_amt_paid'];
    }
    $row       = [];
    foreach ($this->customerHistoryColumns as $col) {
        $order[$col[0]] = ($order[$col[0]] === null ? "" : str_replace("&amp;", "&", $order[$col[0]]));
        switch ($col[0]) {
            ...
            case "due":
                $row['due'] = $order['amt_total'] - $order['amt_paid'];
                break;
            ...
            default:
                $row[$col[0]] = $order[$col[0]];
                break;
        }
    }
    $row['balance'] = 0;
    $row['total'] = 0;
    $arr['history'][] = $row;
}
return $arr['history'];
```

The company itself is defined elsewhere; this is simply retrieving the `history` element.

FWIW, the code has worked flawlessly for years; it's the upgrade to Php7 that has raised this issue.

Comment: Something else is going on here. Code looks fine. How and where is the code for defining `$company`?

Comment: `$company['history']["$i"]['total']` maybe?  Or just remove the spaces around $i ?

Comment: Did you try `print_r` the $compay? It should be because the $company data has some unexpected format

Comment: (Y’all are aware what _potential_ means though, right?)

Comment: @gihan -- yes; there is nothing in the data that is unusual.  This code has been stable for many years, and continues to run just fine now under php7.